# Prolog: how can I change the output of combinations(N, [H|T], P) to return a list of pairs, rather than just the first one before ;?

Tags: prolog

Prolog: How can I change the output of *combinations(N, [H|T], P)* to return a list of pairs, rather than just the first one before ; ? The program works well as long as I press ; in the command line, but I want to return directly a list of pairs.

```
comb(1, [H|_], [H]).
comb(N, [H|T], [H|C]) :- N1 is N - 1, N1 > 0, comb(N1, T, C).
comb(N, [_|T], C):- comb(N, T, C).
```

This is my program. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3).

> `findall(+Template, :Goal, -Bag)`
>
> Create a list of the instantiations `Template` gets successively on backtracking over `Goal` and unify the result with `Bag`. Succeeds with an empty list if `Goal` has no solutions. `findall/3` is equivalent to [`bagof/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof/3) with all free variables bound with the existential operator (`^`), except that `bagof/3` fails when `Goal` has no solutions.

Example:

```
?- findall(X, comb(2, [a,b,c,d], X), Xs).
Xs = [[a, b], [a, c], [a, d], [b, c], [b, d], [c, d]].
```